# Log4j 2.15.0 DOMConfigurator equivalent

Tags: log4j, log4j2

What is the package or the equivalent class for `DOMConfigurator` in `log4j` version `2.15.0` ?

In an older version 1.7.x it exists in `org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator`, but I can not find it in the new version `2.15.0`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Programmatic configuration is explained in [Log4j 2.x documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [log4j-slf4j-impl / log4j v2 - setting custom log4j.xml destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352815/log4j-slf4j-impl-log4j-v2-setting-custom-log4j-xml-destination)