# Log4j 1.x upgrade with log4j 2.x

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j-1.2.17 and need to upgrade with log4j-2.17 (latest as of now).
In log4j 1.x i am using some internal java class to build log4j configuration programmatically and imported some packages like

```
import org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.RepositorySelector;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.RootCategory;
```

But i can see above packages are not available in log4j 2.17.0.
I checked https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html and https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/log4j2/2.x/all/manual-migration.html but no luck.

can anyone please help me here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to tell you how to replace them if we don't know what you're using them for. Some of them have already been asked and answered (linked duplicates), and some of them have been asked but not yet answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350783/log4j-2-15-0-domconfigurator-equivalent

Comment: You will need to reimplement your class :(

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Erm, they already linked that themselves.

Comment: Hi, I suggest you follow this recommendation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312033/how-to-mitigate-log4shell-vulnerability-in-version-1-2-of-log4j